# Why does the Background property affect the region where clicks are registered?

Tags: wpf, xaml, events

Apparently, setting a `UniformGrid`'s `Background` property affects the control's boundaries. See the following example:

```
<StackPanel>
        <UniformGrid Rows="0" Columns="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="32" Background="Aqua" PreviewMouseUp="UIElement_OnPreviewMouseUp">
            <!--Clicking on this UniformGrid fires the event-->
        </UniformGrid>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"></Border>
        <UniformGrid Rows="0" Columns="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="32" PreviewMouseUp="UIElement_OnPreviewMouseUp">
            <!--Clicking on this UniformGrid DOESN'T fire the event-->
        </UniformGrid>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"></Border>
</StackPanel>
```

Both `UniformGrid`s take up space of the same size when rendered. However, clicking inside the second `UniformGrid`'s area doesn't raise the `PreviewMouseUp` event. The only difference between the two controls is the `Background` property.

Why does the `Background` property affect the region where clicks (and presumably other input events) are registered?

Edit:
If I declare the `Background` to be `Transparent`, the event is raised properly. The interaction is ignored **only** when there's no `Background` declaration at all.

Comment: Other that hearing from one of the WPF designers at Microsoft all you will get are opinions about why that design choice was made.

Comment: @BradleyUffner There has to be some well-known technical explanation. Right...?

Comment: There is no technical reason I can think of that would require this behavior.  Winforms has been around for close to a decade using a different method.  It had to have been a conscious choice by the designers.  My only guess is that they thought this method would have more utility than the previous methods.

Comment: `Transparent` background will let mouse interaction go through, that's a standard behavior in Windows platform. In some case (usually use native api) you can change that behavior. However in this case you can just set the Background to a very transparent color, such as `01000000`. It's hardly visible to eyes but still  provides what you want.

Comment: @KingKing Now the thing is, if I declare the Background to be transparent, the event is raised properly. The interaction is ignored only when there's no Background declaration at all! I'll edit my question.

Comment: good to know that. Looks like it's a good design. You have more options to choose. That is if you want some clickable transparent background, just set the background explicitly. Otherwise (wanting a non-clickable transparent background) don't set it (the default value would be `null` - not transparent).

Comment: @Marton just about the background brush,  Background="#00FFFFFF" is a completely transparent bruush that helps to handle events (alpha transparent brush).